# How to have multiple objects work as one object with rigid body physics

Tags: animation, mesh, physics, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I have 6 objects that I want to behave as one with rigid body simulation

[image]

Comment: why don't you just join them? (ctrl-j) if you don't wanna join, you can use rigid body connect -> fixed

Comment: Hello, INeed.. A general answer is often best prompted by a specific example. That would tell us, for example, _why_ you might not want to join the objects, in your case.

Comment: Hello please give more informations, maybe show some screenshots, it's too vague for the moment

Comment: I have added a .blend file, I want the clock to fall while still having the animation for the handles

Comment: Ctrl-J makes the animation not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With clarification in comments: you have a clock; you want it to fall, while its animated hands fall with it but continue to rotate as they've been animated.

From your blend file, which has the hands already animated: parent each hand, Plane and Plane.001, to the clock body, Cylinder.  Give Cylinder rigid body physics.  Give the floor, Plane.002, rigid body physics, and set those physics to passive.  Do not give any physics to the hands.  Run the simulation.

After changing the starting orientation, and running a few frames:

[image]

Note the hierarchy in the outliner.